Bond angles in dinitrogen pentoxide (N2O5)
This is the structure of dinitrogen pentoxide ($\ce{N2O5}$):

I'm curious as to why the $\ce{N – O – N}$ angle is less than the $\ce{O – N – O}$ angle (112° and 134° respectively.) Shouldn't it be the opposite due to steric hindrance?

To begin with, do you understand why there is an angle in the first place? Why is N-O-N not $180^\circ$?

Oxygen has lone pairs, and due to hybridization, right? @IvanNeretin

Right. How many of them?

2 lone pairs, and sp3 hybridized, right? @IvanNeretin

Correct. Hence, a tetrahedral angle (109-something). Bulky substituents make it greater, but not by much. Now what do we have at N?

I don't know at N. We have 3 bond pairs and 1 electron. What to do with it? Like is it SP2 or SP3? @IvanNeretin

We don't have unpaired electrons here. Better think of N as having positive charge (balanced by the partial negative charges on terminal oxygens). It is sp2, hence a trigonal angle ($120^\circ$), made bigger by the fact that the bonds are partially double.

A look at the Wikipedia article reveals that not all atoms are coplanar; the terminal $\ce{NO2}$ groups twist out of the plane from the central $\ce{N – O – N}$ bond giving the molecule a propeller shape.
This localizes the pi bonding largely within the $\ce{NO2}$ groups so that the central oxygen bonds primarily with sigma bonds and roughly with $sp^3$ hybridization. Hence the near-tetrahedral bond angle at this oxygen.

Start with the idea that some compounds have tetrahedral bonding involving sp3 hybridization. In this case, the s and the three p orbitals are considered equivalent, so the molecule would be symmetrical.

By straightforward geometry, in a perfectly symmetrical molecule such as methane, $\ce{CH4}$, the dihedral angle is arccos(-1/3), 109.471...° .
Ammonia, $\ce{NH3}$, is similar to methane, but with a pair of electrons r3eplacing one hydrogen. This breaks symmetry somewhat, "pushing" the hydrogens closer together to ~107°.
Water, $\ce{H2O}$, has two pairs of electrons replacing hydrogens in the tetrahedron, making the angle yet smaller, ~104.5°.

However, the outer oxygens are bonded to the nitrogens differently -- the Lewis structure posits resonating single/double-bonds, making that part planar, rather than tetrahedral. Ergo, ~134° between those oxygens.

Your comparison would do for central oxygen and its 112, if this is the actual value. 134 for O-N=O is much more than sp2's 120 for nitrate, very close to NO2 radical.
